# C# WPF Tab Navigate to control inside of a ListBoxItem from outside of ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, tabnavigator

I have a window with version text boxes, buttons, and a `ListBox`that expands and contracts. Each `ListBox` item has multiple text boxes. I am trying to find a way to tab navigate from outside of the the `ListBox`to the first `TextBox` in the first item for the `ListBox`. I can get it to navigate to the `ListBox` itself and if I hit the down arrow key it will select the first item but that is clumsy. I need it to tab directly from something outside the `ListBox` to something inside the `ListBox`.

Below is some of the XAML I use for the `ListBox`.

```
                    <ListBox x:Name="add_users_listbox" Margin="2,116,-8,0" BorderThickness="0" Height="322" Padding="0,0,0,0"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             SelectionMode="Single"
                             IsTabStop="True"
                             TabIndex="1004"
                             Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Add_User_Binding}"
                             SelectedIndex="{Binding Add_User_Selected_Index, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">

                        <ListBox.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollBar_Rounded}"/>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomListBoxItemStyle}"/>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
                                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue" />
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.Resources>

                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Height="60" Background="Transparent"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                                    <TextBox Height="26" Width="102" Padding="0,-1,0,1" Margin="2,2,0,0"
                                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                 FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                 TextWrapping="NoWrap" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True" UndoLimit="10" AllowDrop="False" MaxLines="1"
                                                 TabIndex="{Binding First_TabIndex}"
                                                 MaxLength="20"
                                                 TextChanged="first_last_textbox_TextChanged"
                                                 PreviewTextInput="first_last_textbox_PreviewTextInput"
                                                 Text="{Binding First_Textbox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
                                    </TextBox>

                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is likely NOT the ideal way to do this, but it works. First we add a bound tag to the `TextBox` within the `DataTemplate`

```
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListBox_Item_Collection}">

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding First_Textbox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                         Tag="{Binding Index}">
                </TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

For simplicity I bound that tag to the corresponding index in the `ItemSource` collection.

```
                int index = Add_User_Binding.Count;

                ListBox_Item_Collection.Add(new SomeDataType()
                {
                    Index = index,
                    The_Textbox = "Stuff in TextBox",
                });
```

The next step is to add a KeyDown event in the user control that comes before this one. In that event we will find the element with that tag and then use the `Dispatcher` to focus it.

```
    private void Preview_TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            string tag = "0";
            IEnumerable<TextBox> elements = FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(this).Where(x => x.Tag != null && x.Tag.ToString() == tag);

            foreach (TextBox element in elements)
            {
                FocusElement(element);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void FocusElement(IInputElement element)
    {
        if (element != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
            (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
            new Action(delegate ()
            {
                Keyboard.Focus(element);
            }));
        }
    }
```

As you can see, lots of work for something that should be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make your ListBox `IsTabStop="False"` and the LitBoxItemStyle too.
I added this setter to the ListBoxItemStyle:  `<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>`

```
  <ListBox x:Name="add_users_listbox" Grid.Row="1"  BorderThickness="0" Height="322" Padding="0,0,0,0"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         SelectionMode="Single"
                         IsTabStop="False"
                         TabIndex="1004"
                         Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Add_User_Binding}"
                         SelectedIndex="{Binding Add_User_Selected_Index, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar} BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollBar_Rounded}" "/> 
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomListBoxItemStyle}">                     
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
                <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="Continue" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="60" Background="Transparent"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                    <TextBox Height="26" Width="102" Padding="0,-1,0,1" Margin="2,2,0,0"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                             FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"
                                             TextWrapping="NoWrap" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True" UndoLimit="10" AllowDrop="False" MaxLines="1"                                                  
                                             MaxLength="20"
                                             TextChanged="first_last_textbox_TextChanged"
                                             PreviewTextInput="first_last_textbox_PreviewTextInput"
                                             Text="{Binding First_Textbox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}">
                    </TextBox>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

Comment: This does not work. I actually already tried this. Tab navigation skips right over the `ListBox` and `ListBoxItems` completely.

Comment: I found a SUPER janky way of doing it and I will post the answer later. I basically added a `Tag` property and bound that value. I then captured the Tab key from the "preceding" control. I then used the VisualTreeHelper to find that `TextBox` by tag and then focus it.